# Jquery autocomplete - only allow autocomplete suggestions

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I use this [jQuery Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create) - framework for an input field (after input of three  characters the suggestions appear), and I only will allow entries of autocomplete suggestion.

My first approach was:

```
var nameSelectedOverSearch = false;
var availablePersons = [];
$(function() {
    $("#anspr").autocomplete({
        source: availablePersons,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            nameSelectedOverSearch = true;
        }
    });
});
```

the user must click an autocomplete suggestion but it is still possible that afterwards the user change the input.
Is there any possibility to only allow autocomplete inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awesome library https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. I did a full exemple with autocomplete and chosen to compare : https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/uw52snsq/

I think it fits exactly your needs.

Relevant code :

```
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

    $.each(availableTags,function(i,e){
             $("#choosen").append('<option>'+e+'</option>');   
    });
    $("#choosen").chosen({search_contains: true});
```

Comment: But customized entry is still possible!?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function "keyup" in this way you can validate any letter and only allow the options on you list:

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true,
  source: availableTags 
  }).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in availableTags) {
        if (availableTags[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
});
```